# How to increase Docker container default size?

Tags: docker

We have created docker image with default size of 10GB and we have loaded cassandra data now it is full means there is no space. Can anyone tell how to increase the docker container size to 40GB from 10GB without loss of existing data.

Comment: Can you just confirm what storage driver you're using? It's under `docker info`.

Answer (score 5):

The default basesize of a Docker container, using devicemapper, has been changed from 10GB to 100GB. Here is a link to the [corresponding pull request in github](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14709).

> Fixes issue #14678
>
> Current default basesize is 10G. Change it to 100G. Reason being that for
>   some people 10G is turning out to be too small and we don't have capabilities
>   to grow it dyamically.
>
> This is just overcommitting and no real space is allocated till container
>   actually writes data. And this is no different then fs based graphdrivers
>   where virtual size of a container root is unlimited.
>
> Signed-off-by: Vivek Goyal vgoyal@redhat.com

Using the last version of docker should solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is possible (without the losing of the data). Here is how you enlarge the basesize:

1. *(optional)* If you have already downloaded any image via `docker pull` you need to clean them first - otherwise they won't be resized

   `docker rmi your_image_name`
2. Edit the storage config

   `vi /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage`

   There should be something like `DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS="..."`, change it to `DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS="... --storage-opt dm.basesize=100G"`
3. Restart the docker deamon

   `service docker restart`
4. Pull the image

   `docker pull your_image_name`
5. *(optional)* verification

   `docker run -i -t your_image_name /bin/bash`

   `df -h`

I was struggling with this a lot until I found out this link http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/03/daemon_option_basedevicesize/
turns out you have to remove/pull image after enlarging the basesize.

Comment: This solution can be used to resize just one container?

Comment: Will this work in Docker Toolbox also, or just in Docker?

Answer (score 1):

In Docker Engine 19.03.6 on CentOS 7.7 :

I fixed this with the following steps:

`# systemctl enable docker`

`# systemctl stop docker`

`# rm -rf /var/lib/docker`

`# vim /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service`

```
>     # Add storage option    
>     ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --storage-opt dm.basesize=20G
```

`# systemctl daemon-reload`

`# systemctl start docker`