# How do I expand volume size on docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

The default on FS /dev/mapper/docker-XXX is 10GB. I followed other instructions to edit */etc/sysconfig/docker-storage* and add `--storage-opt dm.basesize=50G`. Next I do:

```
sudo service docker restart
sudo service ecs restart
```

I can see

```
# ps -ef | grep docker | grep stor
root      5966     1  0 21:45 pts/0    00:00:01 /usr/bin/dockerd --default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096 --storage-driver devicemapper --storage-opt dm.basesize=50G --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/docker-docker--pool --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_removal=true --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_deletion=true --storage-opt dm.fs=ext4
```

So it looks like it took effect, however when I look into the running docker container it is stll 10GB:

```
# docker exec -it 601f6a9e9418 bash
root@601f6a9e9418:/# df
Filesystem                                                                                       1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-202:1-263443-880571d796b21f307753d4f4ecca2141b85119985fac00001ea2622ce643b45f  10190136 7295128   2354336  76% /
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think that you miss  to pull the image

Comment: the AWS ECS agent pulls the images from Amazon ECR (container repository). This does not need to be done manually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this :
link : [How to increase Docker container default size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994760/how-to-increase-docker-container-default-size)
(optional) If you have already downloaded any image via docker pull you need to clean them first - otherwise they won't be resized

docker rmi your_image_name

Edit the storage config

vi /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage

There should be something like DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS="...", change it to DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS="... --storage-opt dm.basesize=100G"

Restart the docker deamon

service docker restart

Pull the image

docker pull your_image_name

(optional) verification

docker run -i -t your_image_name /bin/bash

df -h

I was struggling with this a lot until I found out this link http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/03/daemon_option_basedevicesize/ turns out you have to remove/pull image after enlarging the basesize.

Comment: I tried that, and did docker rmi on every image I had on the server. Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: try to check the version of docker client and daemon it works for me :
gh-laptop:~$ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.6
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        481bc
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.6
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       481bc
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false

Comment: $ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a215d7133c34aa18e3b72b4a21fd0c6136
 Built:             Mon Mar  4 21:25:23 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       e68fc7a/18.06.1-ce
  Built:            Mon Mar  4 21:26:49 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false