# Docker Toolbox default disk is too small

Tags: windows, docker

I am only able to install a few images on my desktop before I run into errors installing new images. usual error is something wrong with the nnn.tar.gz file. To avoid this problem, I am thinking of re-installing docker. Wondering is it possible to change the default disk size setting when installing docker? It is currently creating a 20G size vmdk/vdi disk, I want one that is 50 or 100G in size. Or am I only able to change the disk size after installation?

Comment: Are you asking about the docker container storage size which is by default 10 Gb?

Comment: yes, the container size. Not sure on the default size, just know it will grow until it hits a limit. The limit is too small to store more than a few dockers i want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this and try this solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994760/how-to-increase-docker-container-default-size). I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I think this web site is for Docker, not docker toolbox. I tried some of the suggestions but the commands don't work, such as docker daemon... Also, I am using the overlay storage driver, not devicemapper. This site does look useful in case i am ever able to upgrade to Docker.